# How to define different properties in one model class due to some flag

Tags: c#

I just dlike to define something like:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public int Prop1 {get; set;}

  // pseudocode
  // 
  if(someFlag)
  {
     public Instance1.TypeThatIsDifferentInDifferentInstances Prop2 {get; set;}
  }else
  {
     public Instance2.TypeThatIsDifferentInDifferentInstances Prop2 {get; set;}
  }

}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: yes... but not this way.  Create a class with a generic type.  Then when you create your class, pass in what you want your return type to be.  I am not an expert, but hopefully someone who is can bang out a simple example.

Comment: You could create two classes that inherit from `MyModel` and depending on this `flag` value, you could return an instance of the classes?

Comment: I need this in one class - the separation is a common way but not in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    // T used in constructor.
    public GenericClass(T t)
    {
        data = t;
    }

    // T as private member data type.
    private T data;

    // T as return type of property.
    public T Data  
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I use a several Types for several properties? How to pass them via constructor?

Comment: I believe you can, but I just can't find a quick example.  Try defining your class as "public class GenericClass<T, K>" for two different types.  For more info, look here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public bool Flag { get; set; }

    public object Prop2
    {
        get
        {
            if (Flag)
            {
                return Instance1.TypeThatIsDifferentInDifferentInstances;
            }
            else
            {
                return Instance2.TypeThatIsDifferentInDifferentInstances;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Instance1
{
    public static int TypeThatIsDifferentInDifferentInstances = 1;
}

public static class Instance2
{
    public static string TypeThatIsDifferentInDifferentInstances = "testString";
}
```